# Docker Swarm Nodes through VPN

Tags: docker, vpn, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a somewhat esotieric Swarm setup with the master node being a Digital Ocean droplet, and Raspberry Pi 2 worker nodes that are stuck behind a network that I don't control that blocks all incoming connections. Because of that it is impossible to connect to any service running on those nodes either through Traefik or through a port.

So my question is: Is it possible to run the two worker nodes through a VPN tunnel (preferably to the manager droplet) and have them be able to accept incoming connections? And would it be possible to access all ports on those nodes through the overlay network?

Thank you in advance and please let me know if you need more information or clarification.

Comment: Hi did you able to get into a solution for this issue?

Comment: @AhmedRashad No I didn't. This was just a personal project so I just eventually gave up.

Comment: Thank you @rushsteve1, and sorry I didn't notice your reply before, I solved the issue I had by binding the container to host ports and used them via hos public IP :(, not the best solution but I used it as work around.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [VpnCloud](https://vpncloud.ddswd.de) which will create a virtual private network for all your VMs/VPS/machines so that they are in the same network and are reachable.

Have a look at their documentation and [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-setup-a-peer-to-peer-fully-meshed-vpn-between-servers-249a9071e714).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible if you customize the ingress and the network interface of the cluster.

You can take a look at the [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#customize-the-default-ingress-network) page from the docker official documentation.

Note: of course you would have to set up the VPN between the different nodes first, then try to use the VPN interface from the master node to enable the tunneled communication.